# how to do projection in spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using `@Query` and I get result like this: `[16315551234, 11111111111]`
that result is from column which data type is String , I tried to loop by For and forEach but get error, 
because data type can't be cast to domain I have

how to loop correct way for that result from `@Query` ?
I am new in Java and I really like to get explaining for this:)

my query :

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT W.whatsappid FROM WhatsappChat W")
List<WhatsappChat> findAllContact();
```

on my @Service

```
List<WhatsappChat> resultPerKey = whatsappChatRepository.findAllContact();
```

when I log the result : it something like this ==> `[16315551234, 11111111111]`

```
WhatsappChat is my @Entity / domain
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets

Comment: just did@RameshKotha

Comment: check my edited post @RameshKotha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you fetch ids of the entity but expect entity in loop.

You need to get query result as a list of strings.

But the right query is :

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT W.whatsappid  FROM WhatsappChat W")
List<String> findAllContact();
```

And for iterating on the list you can do:

```java
List<String> ids = respoitory.findAllContact();
ids.forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
  @Override
  public void accept(String s) {
    //use String
  }
});
```

Comment: if don't use @Query, how ? can u give me example ?

Comment: @poppop I mentioned that in my answer

Comment: I only what whatsappid only that is why I don't want use * to get all column

Comment: findALlDistinct get error : data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllDistinct found for

Comment: @poppop Ok if you want just ids, I update my answer

Comment: the result is same like my Query I mention on my question, how to loop that result then ? that is my question :(
the result is like this : [16315551234, 11111111111]

Comment: @poppop No, Please pay attention to `List<String>`. You need to get the result as a list of `String` (type of id) not `WhatsappChat`

Comment: yes I did , the result is same like that : my service like this public List<WhatsappChat> allContacts() { List<String> resultPerKey = whatsappChatRepository.findAllContact();  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195420/discussion-between-ebrahim-pasbani-and-poppop).